# Remove html formatting from pandas cell

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, jupyter

I have this DataFrame on pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CARGO': {53944: 'Driver',
57389: 'Driver',
  60851: 'Driver',
  64322: 'Driver',
  67771: 'Driver'},
 'DATE': {53944: '05/2015',
  57389: '06/2015',
  60851: '07/2015',
  64322: '08/2015',
  67771: '09/2015'},
 'DESCRICAO': {53944: '\\Salario R$ 788,00\nGratificacao Adicional R$ 251,00\nGRATIFICAÇÃO R$ 512,00\nINSS R$ -104,00',
  57389: '\\Salario R$ 788,00\nGratificacao Adicional R$ 251,00\nGRATIFICAÇÃO R$ 512,00\nINSS R$ -104,00',
  60851: '\\Salario R$ 788,00\n1/3 de Ferias R$ 516,95\nGratificacao Adicional R$ 251,00\nGRATIFICAÇÃO R$ 512,00\nINSS R$ -104,00',
  64322: '\\Salario R$ 788,00\nGratificacao Adicional R$ 251,00\nGRATIFICAÇÃO R$ 512,00\nINSS R$ -104,00',
  67771: '\\Salario R$ 788,00\nGratificacao Adicional R$ 225,90\nGRATIFICAÇÃO R$ 512,00\nINSS R$ -104,00'},
 'NOME': {53944: 'John Smith',
  57389: 'John Smith',
  60851: 'John Smith',
  64322: 'John Smith',
  67771: 'John Smith'}})
```

It renders this output:

[image]]

How can I set up pandas or Jupyter so it will:
1. display plaintext
2. accept line break ('\n')

## **EDIT 1:**

I´d like it to be like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would like the plaintext to be formatted?

Comment: I edited the question. The backslah"\" at the end of the cell was an accident, but I didn´t change it so it would complicate things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these things out, replace the new line character with html line break tag `<br>` and explicitly using `.to_html()` and `HTML` for the display, and also set the `max_colwidth` to be `-1` so that the long line will not be truncated when converting to `html`:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df['DESCRICAO'] = df['DESCRICAO'].str.replace('\$', '\\$').str.replace('\n', '<br>')
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer! it solves the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the problem was solved.

On markdown, $ represents the start of a formula on mathjax. The solution is to inser a backslash before the symbol. Here is the snippet for pandas:

```
def fix_dollar_sign(x):
   return re.sub('\$','\\$',x) # remember regex also uses dollar sign.
df['DESCRICAO'] = df['DESCRICAO'].apply(fix_dollar_sign)
```

.

I wasn´t able to make a new line inside the cell..

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Psidom's excellent answer, you can encapsulate it in a re-usable function. This way you won't alter your dataframe permanently either:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

def convert_newlines(s):
    return s.replace('\n', '<br>') if isinstance(s, str) else s

def show_dataframe(df):
    return HTML(df.applymap(convert_newlines).to_html(escape=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

This opens up some interesting possibilities, like highliting some text on the dataframe html. Here is my try:

```
def highlight_text_on_descricao(df_rubrica = tab, texto='', cor='red'):
    def marca_texto(x,text,color):

        x, text, color, = str(x).upper(), str(text).upper(), str(color).lower()
        marcador_primario =  [m.start() for m in re.finditer(text , x)]
        if marcador_primario == []:
            return re.sub('\$','\\$',re.sub('\n','<br>',x))
        contexto = ''
        for item in marcador_primario:
            marcador_inicio = x[:item].rfind('\n')

            if marcador_inicio == -1:
                marcador_inicio = 0
            marcador_final = x.find("\n",item + 1) 
            if marcador_final == -1:
                contexto +=  "<font color='" + color + "'><b> " + x[marcador_inicio:]
            else:
                contexto +=  "<font color='" + color + "'><b> " + x[marcador_inicio:marcador_final
                            ] + '</font color></b>'
        marcador_do_primeiro_vermelho = x[:marcador_primario[0]].rfind('\n')
        if marcador_do_primeiro_vermelho == -1:
            descricao =  contexto + x[marcador_final:]
        else:
            descricao =  x[:marcador_do_primeiro_vermelho] + contexto + x[marcador_final:]
        return re.sub('\$','\\$',re.sub('\n','<br>',descricao))
    df_temp = df_rubrica
    df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'DESCRICAO':'DESCRICAO_LONG_TEXT_STRING____'})
    df_temp['DESCRICAO_LONG_TEXT_STRING____'] = df_temp['DESCRICAO_LONG_TEXT_STRING____'].apply(marca_texto,args=(texto,cor,))
    display(HTML(df_temp.to_html(escape=False)))

highlight_text_on_descricao(tab,'GRATIFICAÇÃO')
```

yelds:

[image]

(by the way, I got added some stuff on custom.css from Henry Hammond(https://github.com/HHammond/PrettyPandas), so that´s why headers and indexes are grey.