# How do I get rid of italics in Ipython Pandas and get plain text?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am saving text to csv file in Python 3.
Text is clean and does not have any tags.
Here is how it looks in Notepad:
[image]

Here is my text bulb:

```
  unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',' '.join(i[1:-1]) 
).encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
```

Here is how I save it:

```
def save(filename, data):
    with open(r"path to file\{}.csv".format(filename),"a",encoding="utf-8"  ) as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, [coulm names],lineterminator="\n")
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(data[:10])
```

When I open file in Ipython Pandas as DataFrame I can see different styling of text like this:
[image]

How do I get rid of it and make all text look the same?
P.S. everything looks fine in gsheets:
[image]
PS. I use the follofing command in pandas:

```
data_full = pd.read_csv("restaurant_menu_with_entryurl_full.csv", encoding = 'utf8')
```

PS. Also if I select single column view in pandas the text looks uniform.
[image]

Comment: How do you open your file in IPython? Please show us a part of the file. Does it contain HTML tags?

Comment: @9769953 Looks perfectly fine. Please see updated info in main post.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille  Please see main post (updated) for details.

Comment: The problem is that you are opening your document in a Markdown cell, and the text between `$` signs gets interpreted by MathJax. Either change the cell type to raw, or escape the dollar signs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089089/escaping-dollar-sign-in-ipython-notebook).

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille how do I make column a raw format? I tried astype(raw) but getting error.

Comment: 'Cell' menu of Jupyter, or in the toolbar.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille it does smth else. And you cant run the code in this mode.

Comment: @9769953 not sure I follow u. This happens inside DataFrame as u can see from the images posted.

Comment: @9769953 That is a fair notice. Thanks  a lot. Have adjusted the Post.

Comment: Thanks. With a previous comment about the dollar signs & MathJax in mind (and I see there are dollar signs missing in the rendered dataframe output, so they are indeed being interpreted), try the solution given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336991/remove-html-formatting-from-pandas-cell): `df[columns] = df[columns].str.replace('$', '\\$')`, or variants thereof. If that works, perhaps your question is essentially a duplicate of that question (and the question is effectively: how do I avoid MathJax in Jupyter dataframe output?).

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue. After digging a bit I found out that there is an option on Pandas to disable MathJax. Try doing this right after you import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.html.use_mathjax', False)
```

Reference for more display options on pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

From the link above:
"When True, Jupyter notebook will process table contents using MathJax, rendering mathematical expressions enclosed by the dollar symbol."

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue.  Apparently the dollar sign initiates MathJax commands.  I could not find a way to *reliably* turn off *all* MathJax processing, so I worked around the issue by replacing all dollar signs in my output with the unicode "Fullwidth Dollar Sign" character, which is either `U+FF04` or `&#65284`.

In my personal case, I was crafting strings to be used as HTML pre-formatted text within a Jupyter Notebook cell, so my full escaping code looks like this:

```
from html import escape

def _html_escape(escape_me):
    '''
    Unicode dollar signs (in case I want to jazz things up later) from https://www.alt-codes.net/dollar-sign.php:
    $   Dollar Sign U+0024  &#0036
    ﹩   Small Dollar Sign   U+FE69  &#65129
    ＄   Fullwidth Dollar Sign   U+FF04  &#65284
      Heavy Dollar Sign   U+1F4B2 &#128178
      Dollar Banknote U+1F4B5 &#128181
      Money Bag   U+1F4B0 &#128176
      Money With Wings    U+1F4B8 &#128184
      Currency Exchange   U+1F4B1 &#128177
      Money-Mouth Face    U+1F911 &#129297
    '''
    return escape(escape_me, quote=True).replace('$', '\uFF04').replace('\n', '<br>')
```